# Linux dynamic routing from host to virtual 'guest' appliance if 'available'

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I'm running a debian host, with eth0 and wlan0 interfaces (I'm calling these host:eth0 and host:wlan0 for clarity) both set to DHCP as normal, and everything is working perfectly well. What I'm trying to pin down here is the best way to integrate an optional virtual machine as a higher priority route to the outside world - I'll explain what i mean.

What I want to do is to choose to run my virtualbox guest appliance, and when it's active it becomes my internet router from host into virtual machine, through internal routing in virtual machine and out of virtual machine to NAT route to internet.

When the virtual guest is not running, that route into the virtual guest appliance is not there so route traffic to normal device/interface...

Elaborating a little further I have a virtualbox virtual machine running on my guest with 2 virtual network cards eth0 and eth1 (I'm calling these guest:eth0 and guest:eth1).

The first of these, guest:eth0 is set to using the virtualbox 'NAT' network interface - which in effect means it'll acquire a route out of my active host:eth0 or host:wlan0 - whichever is active. This is working perfectly well - i can connect to the internet via guest:eth0 via the NAT style of virtual box networking.

The second guest interface, guest:eth1 is defined as a static (non-routable) address 10.152.152.10/18 with the intention that this allows the host to establish routing to a known endpoint (aka the route into the virtual guest appliance, which then internally routes out of guest:eth0 to the internet).

In relation to guest:eth1 I've decided to use the VirtualBox Host-Only-Networking option which, when configured with address 10.152.152.11/18, adds a new host:vboxnet0 interface to my host, and thus makes the route to my virtual guest available (given the host:vboxnet0 interface and guest:eth1 interface are in the same 10.152.152.x/18 subject.

Pausing for breath, even though I'm not sure on the right routing configuration or style of configuration, I'm happy that through various permutations of routing:

1. My host can access the internet via DHCP on host:eth0 and host:wlan0
2. My guest can access the internet guest:eth1 via the virtualbox NAT
3. My host can connect to my guest via host:vboxnet0

So the challenge.

When my host:vboxnet0interface is 'alive' as a result of me running my virtual machine, I end up with 2 default gateways. I'm aware from researching this that i may need 2 iptables - and prescribe 2 default gateways in different routing tables with different metrics....but I've not yet found the one single style of routing configuration which helps me to pre-define static rules which cater for both styles of routing here:

1. When no virtual guest is running (and no vboxnet0 interface available) then happy days, business as usual over DHCP host:eth0 and host:wlan1
2. When my VM is up, and vboxnet0 is alive, it's THE only route from my host to the internet.

I've proven all of the links - but just need guidance on the best routing pattern to now focus on if that makes sense. I was hoping that before dumping iptables/ifconfig/ip route dumps, it may be possible to source guidance from linux routing ninjas on the pattern i need to be thinking of here?

I've spend a few weeks researching/experimenting this and I think I'm making good headway but need a little experience here as I'm running out of relevant advice on the web and circling a little?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is not aware whether the destination addresses it routes to are reachable or not, not with metrics, and not with `iptables`. So you need to somehow detect if the virtual guest is available or not, by finding a place to hook into the startup/shutdown process, or by wrapping the startup/shutdown process in your own scripts and always using these. Hooking into system scripts that get executed when interfaces go up or down is also an options, but that depends on your system (`systemd`, classic ifup/ifdown, etc.).

When you found the proper hooks, just adjust the (single) default route according to the condition of your system in the script(s).